# Unable to change Watermark Colour in mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, watermark, mpdf

I have dificullity to create mPDF watermark except GREY colour and always 1 Line, my question is :

1. It's possible to change watermark colour except GREY? if yes how or where inside mpdf.php i should change.
2. It's possible to change (to make) watermark into 2 lines ?

My Code :

```
<?php
include('../includes/mPDF/mpdf.php');
$file       = "./TMP/dummy.pdf";
$watermark  = "ILLEGAL";
$mpdf_dee = new mPDF();
$mpdf_dee->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $mpdf_dee->SetSourceFile($file);
$mpdf_dee->AddPage();
$import_page = $mpdf_dee->ImportPage();
$mpdf_dee->UseTemplate($import_page);
$mpdf_dee->SetWatermarkText("$watermark", 0.4);
$mpdf_dee->watermark_font = 'Arial'; 
$mpdf_dee->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf_dee->Output();
?>
```

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I don't try everything, but i read documentation at mPDF website (github) but can't find the answer.Please help me, thq.

Comment: use this code to get your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720618/php-gd-create-watermark-change-watermark-text-size-and-background-color-ima/61010503#61010503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watermark text of a different colour than black with transparency is currently not supported by mPDF. Only variables for the watermark are text, transparency, or alpha, and font.

You could use a watermark image of the text in your desired colour - resulting the PDF to be larger in size.

```
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('background.jpg');
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
```

https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setwatermarkimage.html

Comment: Actually my watermark is a variable, it's watermarking pdf using the username of the current user who is logged in, so it will be more complex if I use image as watermark.

I think I should wait until mPDF implements this feature in the future, this is a great tool, but still too few features for watermarking.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, feel free to issue a feature request at the [mPDF repo](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) on GitHub. Also, please consider upvoting and/or marking the response as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here in my code, i fixed some common mistakes like :

1) Watermark Text goes outside of the image.

2) PNG & JPG image error.

So i calculate image width and decide font size. so font size is Dynamic.

so you can just copy my method and paste where you want to use it.

```
 function waterMark($SourceFile,$ext='png',$WaterMarkText)
 {
   if( $ext == "jpg" or  $ext == 'jpeg')
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($SourceFile);
   else
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($SourceFile);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($SourceFile);
$font = public_path('fonts/arial.ttf');
$size = $width*4/100;  // calculating font size based on image width.

# calculate maximum height of a character
$bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, 'ky');
$x = 8; $y = 8 - $bbox[5];

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($image, $size, 0, $x + 1, $y + 1, $black, $font, $WaterMarkText);
imagettftext($image, $size, 0, $x + 0, $y + 1, $black, $font, $WaterMarkText);
imagettftext($image, $size, 0, $x + 0, $y + 0, $white, $font, $WaterMarkText);

//header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
// imagejpeg($image, null, 90);

if ($SourceFile <> '') {
    imagejpeg ($image, $SourceFile, 100);
} else {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
};
imagedestroy($image);
   return 1; // you can remove it...
}
```

Comment: SourceFile should be a public path or physical path. like (..../www/public/image/jk1.jpg). for this method .you have to save your file in disk first.