# Watermark text using imagettftext

Tags: php, image, watermark

I am trying to add watermark (text from input) to .jpg image (from input) and define position, it's fine for one line but for more - starts moving to the left:

[image]

**Update:**

```
echo $the_box["width"] - 1132,
echo $the_box["height"] - 25
```

but my image is 1024x768.

```
if (isset($_POST['TextToUpload'])) {
   $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);//jpg. to add watermark(text)

$font = 'Roboto-Black.ttf'; // font path
$font_size = 25;
$font_color =  imagecolorresolvealpha($im, 255, 255, 255,$tr1);//tr1 - var to define % of opacity
$text = $wt;// wt - text from input  $wt = $_POST['TextToUpload'];  
$lines = explode('|', wordwrap($text, 15, "\n", true)); //15 sumbols - line limit

$text_angle=0;//var for angle
$text_padding    = 10; //some padding
$imageX = imagesx($im)+ $text_padding;
$imageY = imagesy($im)+ $text_padding;
$the_box        = calculateTextBox($text, $font, $font_size, $text_angle);
$y=$the_box["top"] + ($imageY / 2) - ($the_box["height"] / 2);
$x=$the_box["left"] + ($imageX / 2) - ($the_box["width"] / 2);

foreach ($lines as $line){    
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $font_color, $font, $line);
// Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line
@$y += 23;}

imagepng($im, $target_file);
imagedestroy($im);
 }
```

I found lot of info about this issue but using `imagecreate()`.

function calculateTextBox:
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#105593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
$wt_len = strlen($text);//char count
$lc=1;// num lines
if ($wt_len > 15 && $wt_len <= 30) {
      $lc=2;
  } if ($wt_len > 30 && $wt_len <= 45) {
      $lc=3;
  } if ($wt_len > 45 && $wt_len <= 60) {
      $lc=4;
  }

foreach ($lines as $line){


$y=$the_box["top"] + ($imageY / 2) - ($the_box["height"] / 2);
$x=$the_box["left"] + ($imageX / 2) - ($the_box["width"] / (2*$lc));// * num lines to get width of 1 line

imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $font_color, $font, $line);

}
```